# When should I apply a multiple comparison adjustment?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, biostatistics

I am performing a RQL analysis ("http://www.esapubs.org/archive/ecol/E095/002/suppl-1.pdf"). 
This analysis meassures the relationship between different traits of three different matrix showing if there is a positive or negative relationship. This RQL analysis make a fourth-corner method.

Well, this method have the option to  make a p-adjust method to solve multiple comparison problem. However, my variables are independent and I belive that I should not apply to my dataset. Am I right? Or always that two or more matrix are compared I should apply a multiple comparison adjustment?

Comment: [Many similar posts](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com++when+to+use+multiple+comparisons%3F). Have a look!